# mesh animation & boolean: avoid bugs & glitches (Cycles)?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, modifiers

I'm working on an isometric animation where a road scrolls.

The road should appear only within a specific "domain", so I added a boolean modifier on the road mesh, so it is constrained within the desired space.

Thing is, I can't make it work as it displays a lot of bugs & glitches.

[image]

How could I fix this / achieve the same effect ?

Here's [the project file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bb61vzq5999fon9/road.blend?dl=1) if you want to have a look.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The sides disappearing is because the cube you are using for the road domain is a little bit too small, scale it about 0.03 bigger on the Y axis and you will get a better boolean result.

Your second problem is the caps on the ends of your road mesh. By using an array modifier you get these repeated along the road, this leads to the ends appearing and disapearing as it moves along. For this remove the faces at both ends and apply the array modifier, then recap the ends.

[image: road animation]

Comment: wow thanks a lot, i'll give a try.  Regarding your first point (domain a little bit too small), do you know why it would be too small ? Is there something to understand there ?

Comment: @gordie just that as it is, it is the same size as the road, slight variations in float calculations (maybe the displace can alter this a bit as well) mean it can fall on either side of the boolean calculations, sometimes it is inside, sometimes outside, by making it a little bit bigger you ensure it is always outside.